# How can I fix the 'auth/invalid-credential' error while integrating Firebase with Roblox OAuth2 API?

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth-2.0, openid, roblox

I am using the new Roblox OAuth2 API with Firebase OpenID connect provider but when I try to log in or signup with roblox it gives me the `auth/invalid-credential` error. I have entered the client ID and token successfully and here is my code:

```js
function robloxLogin() {
  const provider = new OAuthProvider('oidc.roblox')
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt:'login'
  })
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
      window.location.href = '/dash'
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
      // Handle error.
    })
}
```

I have tried adding the scopes in the code itself and adding the custom parameters. I expect it to show me the Roblox authorization screen (that you also see when you login into Roblox devforum).

UPDATE: I have checked all the credentials and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

welcome.

I don't know specifically the 'roblox' OIDC Provider but, I think:

You must have some credentials like `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri`, etc.

Generaly, when you try to connect to a provider, you must have these informations which you can grap from your provider website. Then before sending any request to the provider, your must configure your client using these credentials according to the provider documentation.

So, unless, I misunderstand your question, I invite you to check your provider docs, grap your credentials then check how to configure your client before sending login request.

Waiting update if any...

Comment: Normally, the client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri are set automatically by firebase.

Comment: I have checked everything and it's completely fine. Not sure what to do next